# Can't log into discuss.area51.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, area-51, login

I can't log into discuss.area51.stackexchange.com. It goes as follows:

- I try to comment on a question there.
- I get a popup requesting me to log in. I click on "log in" and on the next page I enter my OpenID address.
- The OpenID authentication process finishes successfully.
- I get to the original page; the top bar does show my reputation (226)/badges.
- I try to comment on a question there.
- I get a popup: "User does not have permission to comment on this post".
- After refreshing the page I'm back to not logged state (no reputation/badges on the top bar).

Comment: Most likely https issue. Disable "https anywhere" extension or any similar extensions you have.